# menu item for current page is missing a href tag for anonymous user

Tags: users, navigation

drupal 8: 
Theme used "bartik".

If user is logged in, the active menu item has an `<a>` - tag, if not the tag is missing.

**Is this the expected drupal behavior?** btw. the same happens on the language switcher block.

How can i output the a-href tag for anonymous users? This would make theming menus much easier. Thx for any help or pointing me into the right direction

**markup for anonymous user**

```
    <ul class="clearfix menu">
.....
<li class="menu-item menu-item--active-trail">
    c
</li>
```

**markup for admin user**

```
<ul class="clearfix menu">
......
<li class="menu-item menu-item--active-trail">
    <a href="/drupal-8.0.3-clean/node/3" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/3" class="is-active">c</a>
</li>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't seem to get the same results as you. It works as expected on my side. Does it only do that on that particular node, or are all nodes the same? Have you modified the menu template at all?

Comment: its the same behavior on all nodes. the example above is a clean install with only devel modul enabled....but  i get this behavior on all other drupal installations on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by overriding menu.html.twig. You could override menu--main.html.twig instead, if you just want to target the main menu:

### menu.html.twig

```
<li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  ##REPLACE THIS LINE:## {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
  ##WITH THIS LINE:## <a data-drupal-link-system-path="{{ item.url }}" title="{{ item.title }}" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
  {% if item.below %}
    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

I submitted a bug report here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2695619